# Upload Files to MySQL Database using Android HTTP Post

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, upload

Good day guys please help me, I'm already struggling for more than a month!!! I want to upload image to MYSQL database and nowhere else.

What I tried so far:

- Uploading byte array to database=FAIL.(will not upload on server side)
- Connect to mysql database and upload chars as strings=SUCCESS
- Upload bytearray as a string to mysql=FAIL.(again won't upload on server side)

Please give me any full example or even source code how to upload image to mysql database or at least how to upload the link to that image to mysql database and as well as server side PHP code because I don't know php I just need to put in server side by example

Thank you very much beforehand guys, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload a picture to server, follow the below code.

```
 public ServerCommunication() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    }


    public void uploadUserPhoto(File image) {

        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("some url");

            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
            multipartEntity.addPart("xyz", new StringBody("xyz"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("xyz", new StringBody("xyz"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(image));
            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

            mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(ServerCommunication.class.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private class PhotoUploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Object> {

        @Override
        public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            Log.d("UPLOAD", responseString);

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ok i understood but can i upload to mysql database with this codE?

Comment: this code can send you file onto HTTP, on receiving on your code end do whatever you like

Comment: its great but can you give me hint how to use???like I'm setting on click listener and starting uploadUserPhoto() method from your code but i get error,and i think its because MultipartEntity is deprecated,how to solve this?and as well i got no clue how to work with php,what php code i should write onto server side to accept file by your method and send that file as blob onto mysql database??sorry pretty long left but I'm struggling..

Comment: I am assuming you know about, you cannot run network task on main thread in android. For doing that you need to create async task

Comment: oh yeah true i forgot about it ill do that no problem,and what about MultipartEntity being deprecated its ok?now to server side how do i accept my file via php script and store that file to mysql database?or at least the link of my image file to mysql?

Comment: there is a very good tutorial to do that http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Man I LOVE YOU THANKS!ill try and let you know if it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Work for me!
Method in Class UploadtoServer extends Activiy:

```
  public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String lstrArq = SpnListarArquivosCelular.getSelectedItem().toString();
          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog1.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "O arquivo não existe :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + lstrArq);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   String lstrArq = SpnListarArquivosCelular.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("O arquivo não existe  :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + lstrArq);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String lstrArq = SpnListarArquivosCelular.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                String msg = "O arquivo " + lstrArq + " foi enviado com sucesso!";

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "O arquivo " + lstrArq + " foi enviado com sucesso!", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog1.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Erro no servidor", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog1.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog1.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }
```

Cod PHP in server:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "mypatholder/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

BYE!